# FFmpeg desktop recording doesn't work with bluetooth audio source

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, bluetooth

I am working on an application that records portion of Windows desktop screen using FFmpeg. It works fine using command like this

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="Microphone (Realtek Audio)" -f gdigrab -offset_x 0 -offset_y 0 -video_size 300x200 -i desktop -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -r 15 output.mp4
```

But when I change audio source to my bluetooth headset, FFmpeg just hangs and doesn't start recording. Here is same command with bluetooth audio device

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="Headset (QCY-T1_R Hands-Free AG Audio)" -f gdigrab -offset_x 0 -offset_y 0 -video_size 300x200 -i desktop -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -r 15 output1.mp4
```

Can you please suggest how can we solve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36365661/use-bluetooth-headset-device-as-audio-source-in-ffmpeg?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

After trying different things, I finally found out that the ffmpeg recording command was fine but some (or may be many?) Chinese Bluetooth headsets ( I tried QCY AirDots and Redmi AirDots ) do not work properly with Windows and that causes voice recording to fail. Screen recording with audio worked perfectly with another Sony bluetooth headset.